# Хостинг для консольного приложения C#

Tags: c#, .net, хостинг

Здравствуйте! Я написал бота для соцсети, и теперь мне нужно где-то его хостить. Проблема в том, что я не могу разобраться где.
Ранее использовал 1gb.ua, но там бесплатно 10 дней максимум.
Далее попробовал ещё несколько хостингов, но там через ftp. Загрузил, вроде всё норм. А как запустить? Как MySQL установить? Не понятно.
Теперь взялся за Google Cloud. Но тут тоже разобраться не могу.
Может вы знаете какой-то? Или можете объяснить, как работать с Google Cloud? Спасибо!

Comment: Ты хостинги для PHP наверное выбирал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Писать нужно на .Net Core. Вот [мануал](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-aspnetcore/#0) от создания о развертывания на App Engine. Более [короткий мануал](https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/hello-world). Иначе покупай VDS.

MySQL платная в Google Cloud, ценник – https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing
Есть конечно триал на год с 300 USD https://console.cloud.google.com/freetrial?pli=1&page=0 , так же как в AWS и MS Azure.

Comment: На Core есть переписанная версия, а вот о гугл клауде хорошая инфа) Спасибо)

Comment: @Vlad добавил еще инфу, почему о Azure не подумал сразу?